# How to get values from a timestamp indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm constructing a `DataFrame` like so:

```
dates = [datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 2)]
d = DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], index = dates, columns = ['a', 'b'])
```

I want to get a value like so:

```
d[d.index[0]]['a']
```

But I get the following error:

```
KeyError: Timestamp('2018-04-26 16:08:16.120031')
```

How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d['a'][d.index[0]]
```

My confusion came from the fact that `DataFrame` is column first, and not row first as one would expect from general multi-dimension data structures. So in order to get the value, one must switch indices.

```
dataFrame[coumn][row]
```

Thanks @Michael for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get the first element from column 'a', you access it like this:

```
d.loc[d.index[0], 'a']
```

The way you have it written now, `d[d.index[0]]` is trying to get a **column** with name `d.index[0]`.

Comment: My confusion came from the fact that DataFrame is column first, and not row first as one would expect from general multi-dimension data structures. So I could as well get my value using d['a'][d.index[0]]

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to do.

If you just want to first row, you could access it with [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) do the following:

```
d.iloc[0]['a']
```

If you want to filter the dataframe for example by the year, you could do:

```
d.loc[d.index.year == 2018, 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to always know with the type of data you are dealing with, in your case, you create a DatetimeIndex:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-08-25 11:00:00.000307403',
               '2020-08-25 11:00:00.000558638',
               '2020-08-25 11:00:00.002280412',
               '2020-08-25 11:00:00.002440933'])
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>
```

and inside the DatetimeIndex, each element of it is a Timestamp:

```
2020-08-25 11:00:00.000307403
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

As you are working with DatetimeIndexes, you have to index the values by the actual timestamp ('2020-08-25 11:00:00.000307403') and not by the full timestamp variable (Timestamp('2020-08-25 11:00:00.000307403'))

So, instead of doing:

```
df[Timestamp('2020-08-25 11:00:00.000307403')]
```

you should do:

```
df['2020-08-25 11:00:00.000307403']
```

I lost like two hours to catch this error, since it is a bit stupid to include the type of data inside the variable, the easiest way to solve this is just to parse the DatetimeIndex to string.

For your solution:

```
d[str(d.index[0]),'a']
```

should work